# Router redirecting to the another page

Tags: laravel

I have route like

```
Route::get('admin/selfcontacteditdata','SelfcontectController@edit')->name('selfcontectedit');
Route::post('admin/selfcontactupdatedata','SelfcontectController@update')->name('selfcontectupdate');
```

If i just go to my browser and right admin/selfcontacteditdata it redirect me to

```
admin/newsshowdata
```

And my index function is

```
 public function __construct()
{
   return $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{

   request()->validate([
    'email' => 'required',
    'mobileno' => 'required',
    'facebook'=>'required',
     'google'=>'required',
      'map'=>'required',
    ]); 

    $data = selfcontect::find(1);
    return view('/admin/selfcontectedit',compact('data'));
}
```

And my middleware is

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

My rest admin routes are working fine.

Comment: Put your form here code

Comment: give me function code ..

Comment: I had added the edit function code please review

Comment: can you provide the `edit` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but I was writing table name wrong and my file was not saved as .blade please check are you also doing the same thing and there is no meaning of validation in edit function your edit function must be like

```
public function edit()
{

$data = selfcontect::find(1);
return view('/admin/selfcontectedit',compact('data'));
}
```

and your function name should be edit

Comment: Yes my table name was different. It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

[image]You should use **Accept** key not **Content/type**

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to a Route
If in your routes.php file you have a route with a name, you can redirect a user to this particular route, whatever its URL is:

app/Http/routes.php:

```
get('books', ['as' => 'books_list', 'uses' => 'BooksController@index']);
```

app/Http/Controllers/SomeController.php

```
 return redirect()->route('books');
```

This is really useful if in the future you want to change the URL structure – all you would need to change is routes.php (for example, get(‘books’, … to get(‘books_list’, …), and all the redirects would refer to that route and therefore would change automatically.

And you can also use parameters for the routes, if you have any:

app/Http/routes.php:

```
 get('book/{id}', ['as' => 'book_view', 'uses' => 'BooksController@show']);
 app/Http/Controllers/SomeController.php

return redirect()->route('book_view', 1);
```

In case of more parameters – you can use an array:

app/Http/routes.php:

```
 get('book/{category}/{id}', ['as' => 'book_view', 'uses' => 
 'BooksController@show']);
```

app/Http/Controllers/SomeController.php

```
  return redirect()->route('book_view', [513, 1]);
```

Or you can specify names of the parameters:

```
  return redirect()->route('book_view', ['category'=>513, 'id'=>1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect through view, actually your are calling view. 
Correct syntax is

```
return view('view_name',compact('data'));
```

If you want to redirect to any route you have to call like this

```
return redirect()->to('admin/selfcontacteditdata');
```